# One activity, two views. How and where do I inflate the second view?

Tags: android, xml, layout-inflater

I have an activity that can show two different layouts. Both of the layouts are pre-defined (XML). Basically, if a condition is met, then layout A should be displayed. If the condition fails, then layout B should be displayed.

Layout A is a simplistic Linear Layout - it's my main "form", so to speak.
Layout B is a simplistic Relative Layout - it's a placeholder until some data can be downloaded. Once the data is downloaded (and a notification is sent), then I want to remove Layout B and display Layout A.

I've tried calling the `invalidate()` method on Layout B in the `onResume()` method of my `Activity` but that doesn't work.

I'm not sure what approach I should take, in (1) where to "correctly" switch the layouts, and (2) how I should go about displaying it. I'm assuming I need to inflate Layout A when my condition is met, but I'm not 100% sure about that.

Edit:
Snipped of my `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layoutA); // will happen 99% of the time
    ...
    if (!dbHelper.tableIsPopulated()) {
        setContentView(R.layout.layoutB); // show placeholder bc no data exists
        getData();
    }
}
```

Comment: How long does the data take to be downloaded and why aren't you just using an `AyncTask` with a `ProgressDialog`?

Comment: It's a smallish amount of data, typically downloaded in less than 20 seconds (even on Sprint 3G). I am using an `AsyncTask` to get the data. I honestly didn't consider creating a `ProgressDialog` from the `AsyncTask` since it's in an external Java class (i.e. not a public inner class).

Comment: It was, originally, but then I had a need to call it from another part of my application, so I made it an external class.

Comment: I still think you are better off with that. I'm not sure what it being an external class matters

Comment: It may not matter. I did it before I knew as much about Java as I do now. I will try your answer. Thanks for being a sounding board and helping me.

Comment: No, problem. Glad I could help. Like I said in my answer, I believe it will be less expensive than inflating another, essentially useless, `View`.

Comment: Added a note to my answer just in case. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I don't have another Android developer to bounce ideas off of at home. My wife can only handle me talking to her about this kinda stuff for so long. It's always nice to be able to bounce ideas off of people who know understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You are quite welcome and I understand that ;) That's what the community is here for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a reason to not use a background `Thread`, I suggest using an `AsyncTask` and using a progress bar. It will be less costly than using a dummy `Layout` just as a placeholder until you get the data. And you said it won't be used but 1% of the time. Seems like a waste in my opinion

```
 public class TalkToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //do your work here
            return something;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
               // do something with data here-display it or send to mainactivity
    }
```

You apparently know about `AsyncTask` but [Here are the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for future visitors and it has an example of using the `ProgressDialog`.

**Note**

Since it isn't an inner class you will just need to pass your `Context` to the constructor of your `AsyncTask` if you are going to show your `ProgressDialog` from there.