# asynce task not working issuse

Tags: android, background, task

im trying to use the following code in asynce task  cause i want to show asynce task to the user for some reasons.

but this asynce task not working at all...

```
    AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {



            String result = "";
            InputStream isr = null;
            try {


                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();



                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://persiancoder.tk/appservice/service.php");
                //conn.setConnectTimeout(7000);
                //YOUR PHP SCRIPT ADDRESS
                Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                isr = entity.getContent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }
            //convert response to string
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr, "utf-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                isr.close();

                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            //parse json data
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
                String n = "";
                String a = "";
                String j = "";

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (i == 0) {
                        int j1 = json.getInt("id");
                        if (j1 == 1) {
                        } else if (j1 == 0) {
                            AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);

                            dlgAlert.setMessage("برنامه توسط تيم از دسترس خارج شده! لطفا بعدا امتحان کنيد");
                            dlgAlert.setTitle("Server Out!");
                            dlgAlert.setCancelable(false);
                            dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("باشه", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }
                            });


                            dlgAlert.show();


                        }

                    }


                }


            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());

                AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);

                dlgAlert.setMessage("مشکلي نامعلوم پيش آمده!اينترنت خود را چک کنيد");
                dlgAlert.setTitle("Unknown Problem!");
                dlgAlert.setCancelable(false);
                dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("باشه", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        System.exit(0);

                    }
                });

            }



            return null;

        }


    };




    task.execute(/* optional params */);
```

i have tried ways but not working.

whats the problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? This can mean many things. One issue is `dlgAlert.show();`. You can't do this on a background thread. It would need to be done in `onPostExecute()` or elsewhere

Comment: activity runs but not showing warning or even the asynce task.. @codeMagic

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint or log statement at the top of `doInBackground()` to see if the task runs at all? Are any of your logs in the `catch` blocks showing? Is it crashing? And see the update on my first comment

Comment: well i puted just a alert dialog in doInBackgound and got force close but when deleted dialog application worked. so the doInBack() works.... and can u tell me how to optimize following code ? edit it and make it correct... @codeMagic

Comment: So you haven't actually posted the code that isn't working? Because the dialog is still there

Comment: As @codeMagic stated, you can't show an AlertDialog from a background thread (which is what you are trying to do when you call it from doInBackground). Either handle it in a background method like onPostExecute() or explicitly tell it to run on the main UI thread.

Comment: no i deleted the whole codes in doInback() and just puted a simple alert dialog... @codeMagic

Comment: @zgc7009 well how should i make a onpostexecute() and tell it to if the j1==0 (gotted 0 from do in back) alarm the user?

Comment: Send the result to `onPostExecute()` and see [How to use AsyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898039/using-asynctask/18898105#18898105)

Comment: @-Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       super.onPostExecute(result);

   }  so this code must added after do in back ? and can u give me a example of sending result to it? @codeMagic

Comment: Sure, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260855/one-activity-two-views-how-and-where-do-i-inflate-the-second-view/15260998#15260998

Comment: so in doInback i can say  - int j =1; - and then i onpostexecute(); say - if j1==1 alert me... can i do it ??? @codeMagic

Comment: Sure, as long as `onPostExecute()` has access to `j`

Comment: well i tried right now but onpostexe(); cant access to j ! what to do now? @codeMagic

Comment: Declare it as a class level variable

Answer (score 1):

I can't post this kind of answer in a comment or I would, this is AsyncTask 101. In VERY simple terms:

`doInBackground` is designed to perform background operations

`onPostExecute` is designed to utilize the background operation results on the main UI thread

`onPreExecute` is designed to handle any UI requirements prior to running in the background thread

`onProgressUpdate` is designed to perform quick updates to the UI based on the progress of doInBackground

So if you have an AsyncTask like yours, and you want to show a Toast based on the operations of the network request, do something like this

```
new NetworkTask().execute("http://persiancoder.tk/appservice/service.php");
```

Where your NetworkTask class looks like

```
public class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]>{

    @Override
    public String[] doInBackground(String... urls){
         String url = urls[0];
         // Do the code that you already have BUT whenever you are building/showing your 
         // alert dialog, instead of doing that send a result back as an array with your 
         // title and message and show the alert dialog there

         // i.e.
         ...
         } else if (j1 == 0) 
             return new String[]{"Server Out!", "برنامه توسط تيم از دسترس خارج شده! لطفا بعدا امتحان کنيد"};
         ...

         return null;   // return null on success/no error
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String[] results){
        if(results == null)
            return;

        else{
            AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);

            dlgAlert.setTitle(results[0])
                .setMessage(results[1]);
                .setCancelable(false);
                .setNegativeButton("باشه", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });

            dlgAlert.show();
        }
    }
}
```

This, by all means, is not the *best* way of doing things, but it works. I would recommend looking into `Volley` for networking, but this should at least give you a basic idea of how AsyncTasks work.